# Is child process pid() gets assigned to parent process?

Tags: c, linux, unix, process, operating-system

I have read this in books and also in some online forums that child process pid is assigned to its parent. But I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
        {
            printf("In Child Process\n");
            printf("Child process PID : %d\n",getpid());
            printf("Parent Process PID : %d\n",getppid());
        }
    else
        {
            printf("In Parent Process\n");
            printf("Child PID : %d\n",getpid());
            printf("Parent PID : %d\n",getppid());
        }
}
```

It outputs:

```
In Parent Process
Child PID : 2061
Parent PID : 1830
In Child Process
Child process PID : 2062
Parent Process PID : 1161
```

But if I write a wait() function in else block, i.e:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
        {
            printf("In Child Process\n");
            printf("Child process PID : %d\n",getpid());
            printf("Parent Process PID : %d\n",getppid());
        }
    else
        {
            wait();
            printf("In Parent Process\n");
            printf("Child PID : %d\n",getpid());
            printf("Parent PID : %d\n",getppid());
        }
}
```

It outputs-

```
In Child Process
Child process PID : 2044
Parent Process PID : 2043
In Parent Process
Child PID : 2043
Parent PID : 1830
```

I'm not getting why the pid value returned by child process in first code is not the same as parent pid.
While in the second code, it is the same. Can someone please explain the reason for the above problem?

Comment: Have You looked, which process is actually 1830 ? From what I remember, if the parent process runs through, and an orphaned child process still exists, it is taken by process "init" which might be 1830.

Comment: @icbytes The `init` process is *always* process 1. More likely pid 1830 is the pid of the shell.

Comment: Then it is not "init" , thx.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `getpid` returns the pid of the *current* process, and that `getppid` returns the parent pid of the *current* process.

So in the second example, when you call `getpid` in the parent process you get the pid of if itself (the parent process) and `getppid` gets the pid of the *grand*-parent.

The child pid is the value returned by `fork`.

---

More related to your problem is that you have no control over when a specific process runs in a modern multi-tasking system, which means that the child and parent processes may take turn printing out text. In your case it seems that the child process in the first example doesn't get to run until the parent process has printed its lines.

What the `wait` function does, is to actually wait until one child process has exited, and so the parent process will block until the child process has exited.

Comment: Can you please clarify this answer? I'm not understanding how it addresses the OP's question. The OP is not complaining about the different print orders. The reported problem is that in the first case the `getppid` value printed from the child (1161) is not the same as the `getpid`value printed from the parent (2061).

Comment: The OP does make it confusing by printing "child pid" for the `getpid` result in the parent when in fact that is the parent's pid.

Answer (score 0):

Joachim's answer is excellent. As additional note, you can get the child process' pid in the `else` branch by printing the result of `fork`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
        {
            printf("In Child Process\n");
            printf("Child process PID : %d\n",getpid());
            printf("Parent Process PID : %d\n",getppid());
        }
    else
        {
            wait();
            printf("In Parent Process\n");
            printf("Child PID : %d\n", pid); // fork returns the pid of the child
            printf("Parent PID : %d\n", getpid());  // because I'm the parent
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Example:
fork returns two processes, In your first example after fork the parent starts execution and prints its pid 2061 and parent pid 1830 (of bash) and the parent will terminate without waiting for the child to finish, So when child starts executing it will print its pid 2062 and its parent has already terminated it is printing some other pid.

You please sleep() before printing parent pid when child process is running and on other terminal use command ps -l to see which pid the child is printing as a parent pid.

Second example:

You are using wait in parent process that is parent will wait untill child terminates thus child process is printing the correct parentpid because parent is still not terminated.